# What does OrderCustom=1 mean?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking at the code below and I can't figure out what OrderCustom=1 means.

```
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending _
    , Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False _
        , Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
```

I've asked google but weren't helped by the first page results. This is also not the first VBA detail question I have not been able to find an answer for. So a bonus question of mine is if you know of a good reference resource where I can lookup things like this?

Comment: OrderCustom=1 means that the sort order is normal. Excel has 4 custom sort orders, so that user-defined custom orders must begin with the number 6.

Comment: [This reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861528.aspx) might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That implies there is some form of customized ordering on. OrderCustom changes the custom sort property.

Once the CustomOrder is set you should be able to use it as described in your code.

[This might explain it better.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a23d8de-4ffb-4d8a-9085-cb21fa43253d/problem-sorting-data-in-excel-customorder-parameter)

The VB Code from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sortfield.customorder.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

```
'Declaration
Property CustomOrder As Object
    Get
    Set
'Usage
Dim instance As SortField
Dim value As Object
value = instance.CustomOrder   
instance.CustomOrder = value
```